# How to get back to the latest commit after checking out a previous commit? (When the branch name is unknown.)

Tags: git

I made several commits before I discovered a bug that happened somewhere within the new commits. In order to pinpoint which commit introduced the bug, I checked out several different commits and manually tested each. I am now ready to checkout the latest commit and make my fixes. However, I cannot run `git checkout -` because I have checked out more than one sha. And I cannot remember the branch name. (I have several branches with similar names.) I also do not want to use cherry-pick because there are code changes that must remain in the bug-introducing commit.

How do I checkout the last commit I made, without knowing the branch name, after checking out more than one previous commit?

Comment: If you have checked out a commit by its SHA and are currently in "detached head" mode, what is meant by "the latest commit _on the current branch_"? You are not on a branch. You are in detached head mode. I _think_ I know what you _might_ mean by this, but it would be good to be clear about it.

Comment: Thanks for this clarifying question. I always assumed 'detached head' meant git not only pointed to a previous commit but also tracked what branch you were previously on before you entered detached head mode. Seems I was wrong in my assumption about git knowing your last working branch before checking out old commits.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try saying

```
$ git switch -
```

If that doesn't work, you can use `git reflog` to see what you have been doing recently. That will probably tell you what branch you had been working on before you started checking out individual commits by SHA into "detached head" mode.

Example:

```
$ git log --all --oneline --graph
* e97f1b8 (HEAD -> b2) commit5
* 2483507 commit4
| * 51bcef6 (b1) commit3
| * 24cf012 commit2
|/  
* 0a93483 (master) initial

$ git checkout 2483
Note: switching to '2483'.You are in 'detached HEAD' state...

$ git reflog
2483507 (HEAD) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from b2 to 2483
e97f1b8 (b2) HEAD@{1}: commit: commit5
```

...from which we see that before checking out 2483, I was on `b2`.

And the next time you get into this situation, use `git bisect`. That's what it's for. With it, Git does the checking out of each commit for testing and remembers where you were before the testing started.

Answer (score 0):

Try  $ git reflog

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

git-reflog - Manage reflog information